# how to enter a dot "." in a price input field manually

Tags: vue.js

Here I have written a vue.js watcher. Where if user enters a number in price input field after entering a specific number, comma "," will prompt dynamically using watcher. So here i am unable to enter a dot "." manually I want to enter a "." in this price field how can we do that.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Price" v-model="price" name="price">
```

```
watch: {
    price: function(newValue) {
      const result = newValue.replace(/\D/g, "")
        .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
      Vue.nextTick(() => this.price = result);
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use a the `lazy` modifier in the `v-model` directive :

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {price:''}
  },
  watch: {
    price: function(newValue) {
      const result = newValue.replace(/\D/g, "")
        .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
      Vue.nextTick(() => this.price = result);
    }
  },
  })
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app" class="container">

<input type="text" placeholder="Price" v-model.lazy="price" name="price"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks it is working and i am able to enter dot "." but the existing code watcher is not working then.

Comment: the lazy modifier triggers the watcher when you leave the input